# How to set one USB Sound-card as Playback default device and the other as Recording default device in Raspberry PI 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, audio

I am looking for help about USB Sound-card default setting in Raspberry PI 3.
I think less people encounter this problem.

I can set one USB-Sound card as default device in Raspberry PI 3.
using this commands, and set the parameters like this.

Step1.

> sudo nano ~/.asoundrc

File contents:

> Pcm.!default{
>
> ```
>    type hw
>    card 1
> ```
>
> }
>
> Ctl.!default{
>
> ```
>    type hw
>    card 1
> ```
>
> }

Step2.

> sudo nano /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf

File contents:

> …
>
> #
>
> Defaults.ctl.card 1
>
> Defaults.pcm.card 1
>
> …

But I meet one application scenario which need to **generate sound wave for Sound-card A,and record sound from Sound-card B**. The question pop up that it must set Sound-card A as playback default device, and set Sound-card B as recording default device. I find this setting is supported by ubantu, but I didn't sure it is supported by Raspbian jessie (Version 8.0).If Raspbian support this setting , 
which parameters need to be setted.

I try to set 'pcm'and 'ctl' as different Sound-card index. But it fail to effect. My setting is like this:

Step1.

> sudo nano ~/.asoundrc

File contents:

> Pcm.!default{
>
> ```
>    type hw
>    card 1
> ```
>
> }
>
> Ctl.!default{
>
> ```
>    type hw
>    card 2
> ```
>
> }

Step2.

> sudo nano /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf

File contents:

> …
>
> #
>
> Defaults.ctl.card 2
>
> Defaults.pcm.card 1
>
> …

If experts have some advice ,please help me.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I think your formatting is messed up, could you fix it to all be code?

Comment: Ok, thanks very much. I will check and correct it now.